# Auto-suggest text box from a gridview column

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, asp.net

I need an auto-suggest text-box in SharePoint 2010 visual web part which should suggest the values from a column in a grid view. Please let me know if you have any inputs regrading the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SPServices that is a free library which abstracts from SharePoint web services. You have a Method called SPAutocomplete to get the results from a list and a column

[SPServices Autocomplete](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPAutocomplete&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: SPAutoComplete is used for displaying values from a particular list. My issue is that I have multiple lists whose value I am integrating and showing it in a grid view. I want the value of a particular column to come up as an auto-suggest in my text box.